# Pulling one value by specifying another

Tags: xml, xpath

For the following XML snippet -

```
<response uri="http://campaigns.zoho.com/api/recentsentcampaigns" version="1">
  <status>success</status>
  <code>0</code>
  <recent-sent-campaigns>
        <campaign no="1">
              <fl val="campaign_key">somekeyvalue</fl>
              <fl val="sent_date_string">08 Jun 2015, 11:55 PM</fl>
              <fl val="sent_time">1433850936000</fl>
              <fl val="campaign_name">Test for Mailing List</fl>
              <fl val="created_date_string">08 Jun 2015, 10:38 PM</fl>
              <fl val="campaigntype">normal</fl><fl val="created_time">1433846306000</fl>
        </campaign>
  </recent-sent-campaigns>
```

I want to get the campaign_key text by specifying the campaign_name text. I know how to return the campaign_key text by specifying the campaign no (in this case, "1") but I need to be able to pass the campaign_name as an argument (in this case, "Test for Mailing List") and return the key (in this case, "somekeyvalue ").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve a campaign key based on its name, use

```
/response/recent-sent-campaigns/campaign[fl[@val = 'campaign_name'] = 'Test for Mailing List']/fl[@val = 'campaign_key']
```

which means

```
/response                   select the `response` element
/recent-sent-campaigns      select its children `recent-sent-campaigns`
/campaign                   select its children `campagin`
[fl[@val = 'campaign_name'] but only if there is a child element called `fl` which has an
                            attribute called `val` whose value is "campaign_name"
= 'Test for Mailing List']  and only if the text content of that `fl` element is "Test for
                            Mailing List"
/fl[@val = 'campaign_key']  of any elements satisfying this condition, select their
                            children `fl` where there is an attribute `val` whose value is
                            equal to "campaign_key"
```

and yields as a result:

```
<fl val="campaign_key">somekeyvalue</fl>
```

if you meant to only return the text content of this element, append `/text()` at the end:

```
/response/recent-sent-campaigns/campaign[fl[@val = 'campaign_name'] = 'Test for Mailing List']/fl[@val = 'campaign_key']/text()
```

and the result will be

```
somekeyvalue
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to have the campaign name be a variable? How would XPATH treat it? I've seen the $ character used but tech support on this particular system (a popular CRM) is of no help at all.

Comment: @Jonathan Variables with `$` are not part of XPath - they are included in a few languages that _use_ XPath - XQuery for example. You would at least have to disclose the name of this popular CRM, because the interplay between this higher-level environment and XPath with respect to variables is very specific.

Comment: Ah, that's what I wasn't understanding from other references. I did find out what works, though. It is in Zoho and they use the Deluge scripting environment. The code that worked is  
    '" + variablename + "'

Comment: @Jonathan Alright, for your future questions, please always include the environment / programming language right away - then we can give more precise answers. Also, I'd like to ask you to [accept one of the answers given here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) because I think they still answer the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would not relied on the exact knowledge of the xml structure. We can find the relevant fl and take  `fl campaign_key` under the same parent

```
//fl[@val="campaign_name" and .="Test for Mailing List"]/../fl[@val="campaign_key"]/text()
```

Comment: Neither `f1` nor `fi` occur in this document. Also, you definitely _should_ rely on the document structure if it is stable enough, and only resort to `//` if it is unpredictable or unpredictably nested.